# Why can't my site receive the claims from ADFS 2.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wif, adfs

I have successfully configured ADFS 2.0 on Windows Server 2012, and let it trust with my Web Application (ASP.NET MVC 4), but now I receive two default claims from ADFS, `authenticationmethod` and `authenticationinstant`.

All I configure in the ADFS console -> issues claims with my application doesn't work (like email,phone number).

I try to edit web.config, add the node `claimType` like below.

```
<system.identityModel>
  <identityConfiguration>
    <claimTypeRequired>
      <claimType type=URI optional=xs:boolean >
      </claimType>
    </claimTypeRequired>
  </identityConfiguration>
</system.identityModel>
```

But it throws an exception `"Unrecognized element 'claimTypeRequired'"`.

Did I miss any step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Use the On-Premises Organizational Authentication Option (ADFS) With ASP.NET in Visual Studio 2013](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/02/12/use-the-on-premises-organizational-authentication-option-adfs-with-asp-net-in-visual-studio-2013/) and ensure you follow the steps.

You can display the claims as per [How To: Build Claims-Aware ASP.NET MVC Web Application Using WIF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh291061(v=vs.110).aspx).

Are you sure that there are values in AD? You do not get claims for null values.

Comment: Yes you are right! I check my AD store discover I no set the email address to account, very thanks. But why ADFS don't send a empty claims for null value?

Comment: That's how it is designed.